# SVG set as body css background image not rendering

Tags: svg, background-image, socialengine

I am trying to set the background image of my website to be an SVG. The SVG I am trying to use is from http://svgeneration.com/generate/GPlay
I've tested using this SVG as the body background in a plain html file and it worked fine. When trying to add the css for the SVG to my actual website, the website structure and css messes up and none of the css is rendered... It just looks like a page without any css styling. It's like once the browser reads the body background css, it stops there and doesn't go on. So, it's left with the SVG not showing up as the background and the rest of the page css not rendering. For my site I am using SocialEngine (http://www.socialengine.com/). Could it be something with this platform that is not liking the use of SVG?

This is the css I added

```
    body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    }
```

which is the code given in the svgeneration link

Comment: You should provide your code for us to check

Comment: @Zeaklous I edited the post and added the css

Comment: Could you give us some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting another div inside of the body element that wraps everything.  Depending on the content of the page, sometimes the body element doesn't span the entire page.

So you might be able to do something like:

HTML

```
<body>
<div class='content_wrapper'>
  <!--Page Content is here-->
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.content_wrapper{
background: #f0f0f0;
background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,....');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code you have posted. [Here is a jsFiddle showing so](http://jsfiddle.net/h8P2n/2/)

That means that it very well could be a problem with SocialEngine, but before we assume that you should copy and paste the code you currently have into a jsFiddle or some other editor to see if it works. The issue is not with anything you have provided us thus far

One thing I did notice is that the code after the `background-image` line *appears* to be incorrect formatting (it turns blue in jsFiddle like it's a value), but it still functions correctly. You could try placing any code you have before the `background-image` line to see if that fixes it as well